# SSL Error in Ruby on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: ruby, ssl

When I'm trying to connect to a WSDL( I'm writing a client to connect to a WSDL), I'm getting following error:

```
>/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:36:in `rescue in request': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (HTTPI::SSLError)
```

Ruby Version :2.1, Windows 7 64bit OS. Following are the options i tried

```
1. I tried changing source to http://rubygems.org/ instead of https://rubygems.org/ as suggested in some posts..

2. I updated gem version to 2.2.3 
3. Added Cacert.pem
```

None of these helped..

Could you let me know how this can be solved?
Stuck with this issue for past few days.
Appreciate help

Comment: How did you install Ruby? It might be missing certificates in the SSL component.

Comment: I installed it from http://railsinstaller.org/en. So how could i resolve this error?

Comment: If installing another version fails to resolve this, could be a bug in the package. Might be worth following up with their [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/railsinstaller).